# Entity Framework Relationships between two views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to write a Query that joins two of my views in the results.  Not sure why I can't get this to work:

```
var query = AccountUnitOfWork.Accounts.Find()
    .Join(AccountUnitOfWork.Subscriptions.Find(), x => x.ID, s => s.ID);
```

Is this something that I would need to write raw SQL for since Entity cannot pick up on the relationship?

Comment: Is AccountUnitOfWork an Entity Framework dbcontext?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find returns an entity, it does not return an IQueryable.  Join only works on an IQueryable.

Further, your query within the Join would not work either, as that too returns a single entity.

You would need to do something like this:

```
AccountUnitOfWork.Accounts.Join(AccountUnitOfWork.Subscriptions, x => x.ID, s => s.ID)
```

You would probably want to limit that set with a Wher clause as well.